# HTML Forms post redirect

Tags: html, forms, redirect, post, cookies

I've got an HTML form that I'm posting to a url successfully. However, I need to have the page be redirected after I've posted the form. I'm not able to use `ajax` because `CORS` is not enabled. When I post to the url I'm getting a success message, and a redirect link in `json` format. This seems much easier than it's proving to be.

What I know is, when I post to the original url, a cookie is created, and when I go to the url that the page is returning, I am an authenticated user. So, it seems that I need to capture that cookie, and then redirect, but I could be off base.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved using custom scripting.

The script waits for the input button to be clicked and sets up a listener that checks to see if the div that holds the confirmation text is visible and then sends the user to the destination page.

Add this to the code injection point for the page that holds the form:

```
     <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

var eventposted=0;

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('input.button').click(function() {
    window.setInterval(foo, 100);
  });
});

function foo(){
  if(($(".form-submission-text").is(':visible')) && (eventposted==0)){
    window.location = "http://www.something.com/destinationpage";
    eventposted=1;
  }
}

</script>
```

Comment: This does what I'm expecting, however, now my post is not returning 200. If I remove this block of code, I get my 200 again.